# MySQL - Contains Multiple Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables (normalized) with the following data:

```
Customer Type:
+------------------+---------------------+
| customer_type_id |     description     |
|        1         |       customer      |
|        2         |   former customer   |
|        3         |      prospect       |
|        4         | center of influence |
+------------------+---------------------+

Queue:
+----------+------------------+---------+------------+
| queue_id | customer_type_id | user_id | send_date  |
|     1    |         1        |    1    | 2018-02-12 |
|     2    |         1        |    2    | 2018-01-01 |
|     3    |         4        |    1    | 2018-01-01 |
+----------+------------------+---------+------------+
```

I am wanting to query the Queue table, but I'm allowing the user to filter for multiple customer_type_id values. I understand that I can use multiple conditions in the WHERE clause like the following:

```
WHERE
  `user_id` = 1 AND
  (`customer_type_id` = 1 OR
  `customer_type_id` = 4)
```

But since I'm using PHP on the back-end, sending the data via an AJAX request, and the HTML markup looks like this: `<select name="customers[]">`, I'd like to know if there is a way to simply pass the PHP array as a parameter in the SQL command, something like the following pseudo code:

```
WHERE
  `user_id` = 1 AND
  `customer_type_id` CONTAINS [1, 4]
```

The reason for this is that I'd much rather implement built in MySQL methods rather than building a dynamic SQL command during run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, use the `IN ()` predicate. It's logically equivalent to using `OR` for multiple terms as you showed.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

But you should be careful to prevent SQL injection. If you simply use PHP `implode()` to put together an unsafe request argument, you are at risk.

You can either implode() the values cast to `int`:

```
$cust_type_list = implode(',', array_map('intval', $_GET['customers']));
$sql = "...WHERE customer_type_id IN ($cust_type_list);
```

Or you can use SQL query parameters in equal number to the count of the array:

```
$cust_types = (array) $_GET['customers'];
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(1, count($cust_types), '?'));
$sql = "...WHERE customer_type_id IN ($placeholders);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($cust_types);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm already using named parameters (PDO not MySQLi) and so with a few adjustments I was able to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

how about using PHP function [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and SQL in?

```
WHERE customer_type_id IN (implode(',', $_GET['customers']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a String from the array an use the SQL IN()

See the example:

```
$string = join(", ", $array);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE customer_type_id IN (".$string.")
```

If you wnat to add Strings yo have to chnage replace the join through an for loop like

```
$string = "";
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
   if($i > 0) 
     $string += ", ";
   $string += "'".$value."'";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE column IN (".$string.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be the MySQL **[`IN` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)** in combination with a PHP array:

```
$valus = array(1, 4);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Queue` WHERE `user_id` = 1
           AND `customer_type_id` IN (" + $values + ")";
```

Which gets evaluated as the raw MySQL you can use independently of PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM `Queue` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `customer_type_id` IN (1, 4)
```

Alternatively, if you want to select any value in the range, you can use the **[`BETWEEN` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)**:

```
SELECT * FROM `Queue` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `customer_type_id` BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

Hope this helps!